# How to do xpath of existing xpath variable?

Tags: marklogic

I am trying to use xpath on already xpath element using javascript query. Below code giving error

[javascript]

> JS-JAVASCRIPT: b.xpath("/cart") -- Error running JavaScript request: TypeError: undefined is not a function.

```
var a = cts.doc("/users/mydoc.xml");

var b = a.xpath("/user/carts");

b.xpath("/cart");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xpath` function in Server-side JavaScript returns a Sequence. Either iterate over that, or if you expect only one result, apply `fn.head` on it. Also make sure to use relative XPaths if continuing from a descendant. Prefix your path with `.`, or just use relative paths:

```
var a = cts.doc("/users/mydoc.xml");

var b = fn.head(a.xpath("/user/carts"));

b.xpath("cart");
```

HTH!